# Negative Binomial Random Variable Question

Tags: statistics, probability-distributions, variance, moment-generating-functions, expected-value

I am stuck with the question below.

If *X* is a negative binomial random variable, then $$ Y=r+x $$ is the total number of trails necessary to obtain *r S*'s. Obtain the moment generating function of *Y* and then it's mean value and variance. Are the mean and variance intuitively constant with the expressions for *E(X)* and *V(X)*? Explain.

I know that the moment generating function of a negative binomial is:
$$ M_X(t)=\frac{p^r}{[1-e^t(1-p)]^r}. $$
How do I use relate this to the moment generating function I need when I add a constant? I can find the mean by deriving this moment generating function and plugging in 0 for *t*. I also know how to use the shortcut to find variance. Does the last part mean I just say that the mean and variance are as expected because I derive away the constant?

Comment: Does anyone know how to add the constant into the generating function? Thanks!

Comment: What is the definition of moment generating function? Mean, variance can be derived from the moment generating function, but do you have to do it that way? And no, "plugging 1 and 2 in for t" would not give the above, why should it?

Comment: What is the other way I can find the mean and variance? Do I plug in $X+r$ for $r$ in the mean and variance formulas ($\frac{r(1-p)}{p}$ and $\frac{r(1-p)}{p^2}$).

Comment: $$E(X+r)=E(X)+r\,,\, \operatorname{Var}(X+r)=\operatorname{Var}(X)$$

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for a connection to the geometric random variable? If $X\sim Geo(p)$ counts the failures and the first final success, we get
$$M_X(t)=\frac{pe^t}{1−e^t(1−p)}$$
But also
$$M_{X-1}(t)=\mathbf E[exp(Xt-t)]=\frac{pe^t}{1−e^t(1−p)}e^{-t}$$

For the negative binomial $Y\sim NB(r,p)$ you got
$$M_Y(t)=\left(\frac{p}{1−e^t(1−p)}\right)^r=\left(\frac{pe^t}{1−e^t(1−p)}\cdot e^{-t}\right)^r$$

So $$Y\sim \sum_{i=1}^r(X_i-1)=\left(\sum_{i=1}^rX_i\right)-r$$ and $X_i\sim Geo(p)$ independent. This $Y$ does not count the r successes, only the failures.